# android Facebook sdk how to post multiple images with a post;

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a post with several images using post request.

I know how to do the one, adding to the bundle "image" + link.

thanx :)

```
 List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        if(this.mAdapter.ivOriginalUrl.size()>0)
            postParams.putString("picture", 
                this.mAdapter.ivOriginalUrl.get(0));
        postParams.putString("name", "myname");
        postParams.putString("message", this.post.getText().toString());
```

now this is part of the code of my posting.

thanx again :)

Comment: Can you brief How you want to post multiple images ? In your code you are posting the image which is right. What else you want ?

Comment: multiple images in one post. this way i can post one photo per post, I want to or three per post.

Comment: please provide the answer for your question